# Trouble with to_csv saving groupby dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, group-by

I want to save groupby dataframe in csv but i am trying to save in csv it is not saving groupby dataframe.

this is data :

[dataframe image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vaMd.png)

i run this code `df.groupby(['Date','Name']).sum()` after that i got

[output image of groupby dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQe6N.png)

but i am trying to save in csv file it save like this

I run this code     df.to_csv("abcd.csv")

[csv file image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NE57v.png)

But I want to save in csv file like
[saving excel file output which i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xqQU.png)

please tell me the solution

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSV files are plain text, The agreed format is each row is separated by newline and each character is separated by `,` in general.

To achieve the formatting you want, you can convert the df into an excel file instead of csv

```
gdf = df.groupby(['Date','Name']).sum()
gdf.to_excel("<path_to_file>")
```

You will need to explicitly install xlwt to achieve working with excel files

```
pip install xlwt
```

Comment: Hi @bhavani Ravi  can i make alignment of words in center in cell ? now it is top in  above case.